# How would I produce random numbers between two values with a Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, gaussian

Very new to Python, doing some exercises in a book. I need to produce 800 random numbers between 200 and 600, with a Gaussian distribution. I've got this far:

```
x = pylab.zeros(800,float)
for x in range (0,800):
    y = random.gauss(550,30)
```

However, isn't this going to produce any number as long as all 800 fit the Gaussian distribution? I need them between a range of 200 to 600.

Comment: If you limit the values it's not a Gaussian distribution any longer.

Comment: How would I get it to follow that shape then, so that 400 would be the number that occurs the most?

Comment: You could check whether y is between 200 and 600. Not very clean but still simple

Comment: A Gaussian distribution with mean 550 and deviation 30 is very-very unlikely to give you numbers over 800, but it is still possible. You can check explicitly to filter invalid values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Gaussian distribution isn't bounded, but you can make it unlikely that you will sample outside your range. For example, you can sample numbers with a mean of 400 and a standard deviation of 200/3, meaning being outside the range [200, 600] will be outside of 3 standard deviations.

```
mean = 400
stdev = 200/3   # 99.73% chance the sample will fall in your desired range

values = [random.gauss(mean, stdev) for _ in range(800)]
```

If you want to have a bounded psuedo-Gaussian distribution you can do something like this

```
values = []
while len(values) < 800:
    sample = random.gauss(mean, stdev)
    if sample >= 200 and sample < 600:
        values.append(sample)
```

So if you sample a value outside of your desired range, you throw it out and resample.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to generate a Gaussian distribution and then re-scale all the values so that `max=600` and `min=200`.